# How to synchronize start and end keyframes in a loop animation

Tags: animation

In order to create a loop animation of a bone, it is necessary to make the start and end frames the same.
It is very tedious to duplicate the start frame to the end frame every time the start frame is modified.

Is there any way to synchronize this automatically, even if it is an add-on?